# django 1.7 order by related field error

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm fairly new to Django. I've a problem ordering queryset by a related model field. 
I've already seen the similar questions on stackoverflow but I'm stuck with this silly error,

I would like have all the records from "MktIn" ordered by "nome" field from "Squadre" model
The relation is  one (Squadre) toMany (MktIn).
 Following the Django docs I've used the double underscore notation "squadre__nome" but i get this error :

p.s. all except the order_by clause works fine

Could you please help me??

```
>>> tutteIn = MktIn.objects.all().order_by('squadre__nome', 'ruolo', '-ingaggio')                                                                   
>>> print (tutteIn.query)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/bestfoot/.virtualenvs/django17/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 196, in __str__
    sql, params = self.sql_with_params()
  File "/home/bestfoot/.virtualenvs/django17/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 204, in sql_with_params
    return self.get_compiler(DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS).as_sql()
  File "/home/bestfoot/.virtualenvs/django17/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 101, in as_sql
    ordering, o_params, ordering_group_by = self.get_ordering()
  File "/home/bestfoot/.virtualenvs/django17/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 429, in get_ordering
    self.query.get_meta(), default_order=asc):
  File "/home/bestfoot/.virtualenvs/django17/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 465, in find_ordering_name
    field, targets, alias, joins, path, opts = self._setup_joins(pieces, opts, alias)
  File "/home/bestfoot/.virtualenvs/django17/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 498, in _setup_joins
    pieces, opts, alias)
  File "/home/bestfoot/.virtualenvs/django17/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1419, in setup_joins
    names, opts, allow_many, fail_on_missing=True)
  File "/home/bestfoot/.virtualenvs/django17/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1383, in names_to_path
    self.raise_field_error(opts, name)
  File "/home/bestfoot/.virtualenvs/django17/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1389, in raise_field_error
    "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'squadre' into field. Choices are: author, author_id, caratteristica_1, caratteristica_2, 
con_esperienza, created_date, extra_info_1, extra_info_2, id, id_squadra, id_squadra_id, incroci, ingaggio, mod_date, note, parametro_zero, piede, r
anking_in, ruolo, scadenza, sospesa, tipo_in, valore
```

in models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Squadre(models.Model):
    EL_SERIE = (('','Scegli'), ('A','A'), ('B','B'), ('C','C'), ('D','D'),)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    paese = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    serie = models.CharField(choices=EL_SERIE, max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    indirizzo = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    tel_sede = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    fax_sede = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    email_sede = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)    
    note = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    mod_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)

    def upd_date(self):
        self.mod_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

class MktIn(models.Model):
    EL_RUOLI = (('','Scegli'), ('PO','Portiere'), ('TD','Terzino destro'), ('TS','Terzino sinistro'), ('DC','Difensore centrale'), ('CC','Centrocampista centrale'), ('CI','Interno di centrocampo'), ('CL','Centrocampista laterale'), ('TR','Trequartista'), ('AL','Ala'), ('AT','Attacante'),)
    EL_CARATTERISTICHE = (('','Scegli'),(1,'Bomber'),(2,'Box to box'),(3,'Di manovra'),(4,'Di spinta'),(5,'Difensivo'),(6,'Gioco aereo'),(7,'Normo dotato'),(8,'Play'),(9,'Rapido'),(10,'Strutturato'),(11,'Tecnico'),(12,'Veloce'),)
    EL_PIEDI = (('','Scegli'), ('DX','Destro'), ('SX','Sinistro'),)
    EL_TIPO_IN = (('','Scegli'),(1,'Definitivo'),(2,'Prestito'),(3,'Definitivo/Prestito'))
    EL_RANKING = (('','Scegli'),(200,'A'),(175,'AB'),(150,'B'),(125,'BC'),(100,'C'),(50, 'SG'))
    EL_SCAD = [[i, str(i)] for i in range(2015,2040)]
    id_squadra = models.ForeignKey(Squadre)
    ranking_in = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=EL_RANKING)
    ruolo = models.CharField(choices=EL_RUOLI, max_length=2)
    caratteristica_1 = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=EL_CARATTERISTICHE,blank=True,null=True)
    caratteristica_2 = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=EL_CARATTERISTICHE,blank=True,null=True)
    con_esperienza = models.NullBooleanField()
    piede = models.CharField(choices=EL_PIEDI, max_length=10,blank=True,null=True)
    tipo_in = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=EL_TIPO_IN,blank=True,null=True)
    valore = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    ingaggio = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    scadenza = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=EL_SCAD,blank=True,null=True)
    parametro_zero = models.NullBooleanField()
    extra_info_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    extra_info_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    note = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    mod_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)
    sospesa = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def upd_date(self):
        self.mod_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
         return "%s %s" % (self.id_squadra, self.ruolo)
```

in views.py:

```
from .models import Squadre, MktIn, MktOut, Incroci

def lista_in(request):
    tutteIn = MktIn.objects.all().order_by('squadre__nome', 'ruolo', '-ingaggio')
    return render(request, 'market/lista_in.html', {'tutteIn':tutteIn, 'full_path': request.get_full_path()})
```

Comment: try `.order_by('id_squadra__nome...`

Comment: Thanks itzmeontv,  It works!!!
I was sure of having to use relatedmodel__fied syntax, but i was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use,

```
tutteIn = MktIn.objects.all().order_by('id_squadra__nome', 'ruolo', '-ingaggio')
```

It's your field name, not the model name.